# how to implement parental gate in nativescript

Tags: android, angular2-nativescript

I've created an app that uses a set of embed videos of YouTube.
Since this is made for kids, my app after 6 years got removed because I did not implement parental gateway when kids might accidentally click on the YouTube logo - it will load the YouTube app and continue there.

i'm trying to understand how, in general, I can grab such event, that is fired when something ( click ) wants to open another app ( not just youtube ) - and then activate my page that I've created as a parental gateway - and if the answer is correct - then I continue.

EDIT: Was able to do so far:

- I found event that might help `suspendEvent`
- I'm able to catch it and forward to my page
- [stuck] unable to catch the event the loads the native app

DOES NOT WORK: Things that doesn't work so far:

**(1)** suspendEvent, the event is fired when the native app loads - but cannot prevent/disable/control the native app lunch for a "parental gate" in the middle ( youtube app still loaded and in the background - parental gate page is switched )

```
import { on as applicationOn } from "tns-core-modules/application";
...
applicationOn(suspendEvent, this.activateParentalGateway, this);
```

**(2)** WebViewExt

it has an event called `WebViewExt.shouldOverrideUrlLoadingEvent`, but I'm unable to load the YouTube plugin inside it

```
<WebViewExt debugMode="true" (loaded)="onWebViewLoaded($event)">
  <YoutubePlayer id="player" [src]="settings.player.src"></YoutubePlayer>
</WebViewExt>

webview.on(WebViewExt.shouldOverrideUrlLoadingEvent, (args1: ShouldOverrideUrlLoadEventData) => {
   console.log("shouldOverrideUrlLoadingEvent firing for url : ", args1.url);
   utils.openUrl(args1.url);
});
```

is there a native replacement for `shouldOverrideUrlLoadingEvent` ?

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my solution for now, I've seen tons of posts related to parental gate which non were answered.

Not sure if Google Play will accept it, but was able to set a parental gate in my app, please share your answers as well if you find something better !

So I'm using this pkg: https://github.com/Notalib/nativescript-webview-ext, which is a webview component (browser) and my code looks like this

### player.component.html

```
<GridLayout class="page page-content" xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" xmlns:nota="@nota/nativescript-webview-ext">

  ... other html code ...
  <nota:WebViewExt (loaded)="onWebViewLoaded($event)"
                   src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ src }}'
                   width="100%" height="100%">
  </nota:WebViewExt>
</GridLayout>
```

### player.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { WebView } from "tns-core-modules/ui/web-view";
import { WebViewExt, ShouldOverrideUrlLoadEventData } from "@nota/nativescript-webview-ext";

/*
  Events
*/
   onWebViewLoaded(args) {        
        let webview: WebView = args.object;

        // This code will grab any click that try to load/switch to an external app/url               
        webview.on(WebViewExt.shouldOverrideUrlLoadingEvent, (_args: ShouldOverrideUrlLoadEventData) => {
            // Disable the event
            _args.cancel = true;            

            // Switch to parental gateway
            this.activateParentalGateway(_args.url);            
        });        
    }    

    activateParentalGateway(blocked_url) {
        if (typeof(blocked_url) !== "string") {            
            return false;
        }

        // run inside the ngZone to connect the event back to the 
        // component state ( otherwise there's no "this" variable )
        this.zone.run(() => {
            this.routerExtensions.navigate(['parental_gateway', blocked_url], {
                transition: {
                    name: "fade"
                }
            });            
        });
    }
```

### parental_gateway.component.html

This is where we ask some "grownup" question ... for now just made two buttons for testing correct / wrong answers.

```
<GridLayout columns="*" rows="*">
    <StackLayout row="0" width="100%" orientation="horizontal">    
        <Label text="Answer this question please"  width="20%" height="50"></Label>
        <Button text="Correct" (tap)="answeredCorrect($event)"></Button>
        <Button text="Failed" (tap)="answeredWrong($event)"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

### parental_gateway.component.ts

```
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { openUrl } from "tns-core-modules/utils/utils";

    answeredCorrect() {
        console.log("Answer was correct");

        // openUrl will actually open the YouTube video
        // in a native app ( basically continue the event )
        openUrl(this.blocked_url);

        // In the background we want to go back from the 
        // parental gate page that we've been in
        // and switch to the video where we first clicked it.
        this.routerExtensions.backToPreviousPage();
    }

    answeredWrong() {
        console.log("Wrong answer go back");
        // Just go back to our page where we've clicked the link
        this.routerExtensions.backToPreviousPage();
    }
```

Hope this helps others, if so, please vote up.